# Magento 2.4 downloading corrupt files always

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, file, download

I am trying to download a file that is located in the `/media/attachment/` location.

Downloading works with exact file size but never opened. says file format not supported for images, for pdf it says the file is corrupt.

Here is my code, please help.

'''

```
class Attachment extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_pageFactory;
protected $request;
protected $_customerSession;
protected $customerGroup;
protected $attachmentmodelFactory;
protected $_storeManager;
/**
 * @var Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
 */
 protected $_downloader;
/**
 * @var Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
 */
protected $_directory;

/**
 * @param Context     $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    CustomerGroup $customerGroup,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    \PurpleCommerce\Attachment\Model\ResourceModel\Attachment\CollectionFactory $attachmentmodelFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->customerGroup = $customerGroup;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_downloader =  $fileFactory;
    $this->directory = $directory;
    $this->resultRawFactory      = $resultRawFactory;
    $this->attachmentmodelFactory = $attachmentmodelFactory;
    $this->_customerSession = $session;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}


public function downloadfile($currentCustCode,$visibleto,$attachment){
    // if(in_array($currentCustCode,$visibleto)){
        
        $url= $attachment[0]['icon'];
        $dir = dirname($url);
        $subdir = substr($dir, strpos($dir, 'attachment')+10);
        $fileName = basename($url);

        $file = $this->directory->getPath("media")."/attachment".$subdir.'/'.$fileName;
        
        $imageHeaders = get_headers($url);

        /**
         * do file download
         */


        return $this->_downloader->create(
            $fileName,
            @file_get_contents($file)
        );

       // also tried this with no luck

        //return $this->fileFactory->create(
        //     $fileName, 
        //     $content, 
        //     DirectoryList::PUB,
        //     'application/octet-stream'
        //  );


   }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
<?php
 
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;
 
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 
class DownloadFile extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $fileFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $fileName = "test.pdf"; // add your file name here
        if ($fileName) {
            $filePath = 'media/catalog/attachments/file/' . $fileName;
            $content['type'] = 'filename';// type has to be "filename"
            $content['value'] = $filePath; // path where file place
            $content['rm'] = 1; // if you add 1 then it will be delete from server after being download, otherwise add 0.
            $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
            $mediaUrl .= 'catalog/attachments/file/' . $fileName;
            $imageHeaders = get_headers($mediaUrl);
            if (isset($imageHeaders[0])) {
                $imageStatus = stripos($imageHeaders[0], "200 OK") ? true : false;
                if ($imageStatus) {
                    return $this->fileFactory->create($fileName, $content, DirectoryList::PUB);
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__("File does not exist"));
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__("File does not exist"));
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__("Something went wrong"));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```